# Uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a multi step registration form using React and Redux.

The main component is as follows :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../../actions/actionCreators';
import countries from '../../data/countries';

import RegistrationFormStepOne from './registrationFormStepOne';
import RegistrationFormStepTwo from './registrationFormStepTwo';
import RegistrationFormStepThree from './registrationFormStepThree';
import RegistrationFormStepFour from './registrationFormStepFour';

class RegistrationPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: Object.assign({}, this.props.userData),
            fileNames: {},
            selectedFile: {},
            icons: {
                idCard: 'upload',
                statuten: 'upload',
                blankLetterhead: 'upload',
                companyPhoto: 'upload'
            },
            step: 1,
            errors: {}
        };

        this.setUser = this.setUser.bind(this);
        this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.onButtonPreviousClick = this.onButtonPreviousClick.bind(this);
        this.changeCheckboxState = this.changeCheckboxState.bind(this);
        this.onFileChange = this.onFileChange.bind(this);
        this.routerWillLeave = this.routerWillLeave.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
    }

    routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
        if (this.state.step > 1) {
            this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1});
            return false;
        }
    }

    getCountries(){
        return countries;
    }


    setUser(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;

        let user = this.state.user;
        user[field] = value;
        this.setState({user: user});

    }

    validation(){
        const user = this.state.user;
        const languageReg = this.props.currentLanguage.default.registrationPage;
        let formIsValid = true;
        let errors = {};

        if(!user.companyName){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.companyName = languageReg.companyNameEmpty;
        }

        if(!user.btwNumber){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.btwNumber = languageReg.btwNumberEmpty;
        }

        if(!user.address){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.address = languageReg.addressEmpty;
        }

        if(!user.country){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.country = languageReg.countryEmpty;
        }

        if(!user.zipcode){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.zipcode = languageReg.zipcodeEmpty;
        }

        if(!user.place){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.place = languageReg.placeEmpty;
        }


        if(!user.firstName){
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.firstName = languageReg.firstnameEmpty;
        }



        this.setState({errors: errors});
        return formIsValid;
    }

    onFileChange(name, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let file = event.target.value;

        let filename = file.split('\\').pop(); //We get only the name of the file
        let filenameWithoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""); //We get the name of the file without extension

        let user = this.state.user;
        let fileNames = this.state.fileNames;
        let selectedFile = this.state.selectedFile;
        let icons = this.state.icons;

        switch (name.btnName) {
            case "idCard" :
                fileNames[name.btnName] = filenameWithoutExtension;
                //Check if file is selected
                if(file){
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "fileSelected";
                    user["idCardFile"] = true;
                    icons["idCard"] = "check";
                }else{
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "";
                    user["idCardFile"] = false;
                    icons["idCard"] = "upload";
                }
                break;
            case "statuten" :
                fileNames[name.btnName] = filenameWithoutExtension;

                //Check if file is selected
                if(file){
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "fileSelected";
                    user["statutenFile"] = true;
                    icons["statuten"] = "check";
                }else{
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "";
                    user["statutenFile"] = false;
                    icons["statuten"] = "upload";
                }
                break;
            case "blankLetterhead" :
                fileNames[name.btnName] = filenameWithoutExtension;

                //Check if file is selected
                if(file){
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "fileSelected";
                    user["blankLetterheadFile"] = true;
                    icons["blankLetterhead"] = "check";
                }else{
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "";
                    user["blankLetterheadFile"] = false;
                    icons["blankLetterhead"] = "upload";
                }
                break;
            default:
                fileNames[name.btnName] = filenameWithoutExtension;
                //Check if file is selected
                if(file){
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "fileSelected";
                    user["companyPhotoFile"] = true;
                    icons["companyPhoto"] = "check";
                }else{
                    selectedFile[name.btnName] = "";
                    user["companyPhotoFile"] = false;
                    icons["companyPhoto"] = "upload";
                }
        }

        this.setState({user: user, fileNames: fileNames, selectedFile: selectedFile, icons: icons});
    }

    changeCheckboxState(event) {
        let chcName = event.target.name;
        let user = this.state.user;

        switch (chcName) {
            case "chcEmailNotificationsYes":
                user["emailNotifications"] = event.target.checked;
                break;
            case "chcEmailNotificationsNo":
                user["emailNotifications"] = !event.target.checked;
                break;
            case "chcTerms":
                if(typeof this.state.user.terms === "undefined"){
                    user["terms"] = false;
                }else{
                    user["terms"] = !this.state.user.terms;
                }

                break;
            case "chcSmsYes":
                user["smsNotifications"] = event.target.checked;
                break;
            default:
                user["smsNotifications"] = !event.target.checked;
        }
        this.setState({user: user});
        this.props.actions.userRegistration(this.state.user);
    }

    onButtonClick(name, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.actions.userRegistration(this.state.user);
        switch (name) {
            case "stepFourConfirmation":
                this.setState({step: 1});
                break;
            case "stepTwoNext":
                this.setState({step: 3});
                break;
            case "stepThreeFinish":
                this.setState({step: 4});
                break;
            default:
                if(this.validation()) {
                   this.setState({step: 2});
                }
        }
    }


    onButtonPreviousClick(){
        this.setState({step: this.state.step - 1});
    }

    render() {
        const languageReg = this.props.currentLanguage.default.registrationPage;

        console.log(this.state.user);
        let formStep = '';
        let step = this.state.step;
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepOne user={this.props.userData}
                                                     onChange={this.setUser}
                                                     onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                     countries={this.getCountries(countries)}
                                                     errors={this.state.errors}
                                                     step={step}/>);
                break;
            case 2:
                formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepTwo user={this.props.userData}
                                                     onChange={this.setUser}
                                                     onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                     onButtonPreviousClick={this.onButtonPreviousClick}
                                                     errors={this.state.errors}/>);
                break;
            case 3:
                formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepThree user={this.props.userData}
                                                       onFileChange={this.onFileChange}
                                                       onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                       onButtonPreviousClick={this.onButtonPreviousClick}
                                                       errors={this.state.errors}
                                                       fileNames={this.state.fileNames}
                                                       icons={this.state.icons}
                                                       fileChosen={this.state.selectedFile}/>);
                break;

            default:
                formStep = (<RegistrationFormStepFour user={this.props.userData}
                                                      onChange={this.setUser}
                                                      onChangeCheckboxState={this.changeCheckboxState}
                                                      onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick}
                                                      onButtonPreviousClick={this.onButtonPreviousClick}
                                                      errors={this.state.errors}/>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="sidebar-menu-container" id="sidebar-menu-container">

                <div className="sidebar-menu-push">

                    <div className="sidebar-menu-overlay"></div>

                    <div className="sidebar-menu-inner">
                        <div className="contact-form">
                            <div className="container">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-offset-right-1">
                                        {React.cloneElement(formStep, {currentLanguage: languageReg})}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

RegistrationPage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        userData: state.userRegistrationReducer
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegistrationPage);
```

The first step component is as follows

```
    import React from 'react';
import Button from '../../common/formElements/button';
import RegistrationFormHeader from './registrationFormHeader';
import TextInput from '../../common/formElements/textInput';
import SelectInput from '../../common/formElements/selectInput';

const RegistrationFormStepOne = ({user, onChange, onButtonClick, errors, currentLanguage, countries}) => {

  const language = currentLanguage;

  return (
    <div className="contact_form">
      <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
        <div className="row">
          <RegistrationFormHeader activeTab={0} currentLanguage={language}/>
          <div className="hideOnBigScreens descBox">
            <div className="headerTitle">{language.businessInfoConfig}</div>
            <div className="titleDesc">{language.businessBoxDesc}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <h6 className="registrationFormDesc col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-offset-right-2 col-xs-12">
              {language.businessDesc}
            </h6>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="companyName"
                label={language.companyNameLabel}
                labelClass="control-label"
                placeholder={language.companyNameLabel}
                className="templateInput"
                id="company"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.companyName}
                errors={errors.companyName}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="btwNumber"
                label={language.vatNumberLabel}
                placeholder={language.vatNumberLabel}
                className="templateInput"
                id="btwNumber"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.btwNumber}
                errors={errors.btwNumber}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12" style={{marginBottom: 25}}>
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="address"
                label={language.addressLabel}
                placeholder={language.address1Placeholder}
                className="templateInput"
                id="address"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.address}
                errors={errors.address}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12" style={{marginBottom: 25}}>
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="address1"
                placeholder={language.address2Placeholder}
                className="templateInput"
                id="address"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.address1}
                errors=""
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="address2"
                placeholder={language.address3Placeholder}
                className="templateInput"
                id="address"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.address2}
                errors=""
              />
            </div>

              <div className="col-sm-3">
              <SelectInput name="country"
                           label={language.selectCountryLabel}
                           onChange={onChange}
                           options={countries}
                           className="templateInput selectField"
                           defaultOption={language.selectCountry}
                           value={user.country}
                           errors={errors.country}
                           />
                </div>

            <div className="col-sm-3">

              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="zipcode"
                label={language.zipcodeLabel}
                placeholder={language.zipcodeLabel}
                className="templateInput"
                id="zipcode"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.zipcode}
                errors={errors.zipcode}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <TextInput
                type="text"
                name="place"
                label={language.placeLabel}
                placeholder={language.placeLabel}
                className="templateInput"
                id="place"
                onChange={onChange}
                value={user.place}
                errors={errors.place}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="clearfix"></div>
          <div className="col-lg-12" style={{marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 30}}>
            <Button onClick={onButtonClick.bind(this)}
                    name="stepOneNext"
                    value={language.btnNext}
                    icon="arrow-circle-right"
                    style={{margin: '0 auto 60px'}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationFormStepOne;
```

I try to add some simple validation and I've added validation function in my main component and then I check on button click if the returned value true or false is. If it's true, than I set step state to a appropriate value. And it works if I validate only the form fields of the first step, but when I try to also validate one or more form fields of the next step (now I'm trying to validate also the first field of the second step)

```
if(!user.firstName){
        formIsValid = false;
        errors.firstName = languageReg.firstnameEmpty;
    }
```

I get than

*Warning: TextInput is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

Without the validation function works everything perfect.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

```
    import React, {propTypes} from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

const TextInput = ({errors, style, name, labelClass, label, className, placeholder, id, value, onChange, type}) => {
  let wrapperClass = "form-group";

  if (errors) {
    wrapperClass += " " + "inputHasError";
  }

  return (
    <div className={wrapperClass} style={style}>
      <label htmlFor={name} className={labelClass}>{label}</label>
      <input type={type}
             className={className}
             placeholder={placeholder}
             name={name}
             id={id}
             value={value}
             style={{}}
             onChange={onChange}
      />
      <div className="errorBox">{errors}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

TextInput.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  label: React.PropTypes.string,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  type: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  id: React.PropTypes.string,
  style: React.PropTypes.object,
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  labelClass: React.PropTypes.string,
  value: React.PropTypes.string,
  errors: React.PropTypes.string
};

export default TextInput;
```

This is second step component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../../common/formElements/button';
import RegistrationFormHeader from './registrationFormHeader';
import TextInput from '../../common/formElements/textInput';


const RegistrationFormStepTwo = ({user, onChange, onButtonClick, onButtonPreviousClick, errors, currentLanguage}) => {
    const language = currentLanguage;

    return (
        <div className="contact_form">
            <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="contact_form">
                <div className="row">
                    <RegistrationFormHeader activeTab={1} currentLanguage={language}/>
                    <div className="hideOnBigScreens descBox">
                        <div className="headerTitle">{language.personalInfoConfig}</div>
                        <div className="titleDesc">{language.personalBoxDesc}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <h6 className="registrationFormDesc col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-offset-right-2 col-xs-12">
                            {language.personalDesc}
                        </h6>
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="firstName"
                                label={language.firsnameLabel}
                                placeholder={language.firsnameLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="name"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.firstName}
                                errors={errors.firstName}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="lastName"
                                label={language.lastnameLabel}
                                placeholder={language.lastnameLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="name"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.lastName}
                                errors={errors.lastName}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="phone"
                                label={language.phoneLabel}
                                placeholder={language.phoneLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="phone"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.phone}
                                errors={errors.phone}

                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="mobilePhone"
                                label={language.mobileLabel}
                                placeholder={language.mobileLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="phone"
                                style={{}}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.mobilePhone}
                                errors={errors.mobilePhone}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="clearfix"></div>

                        <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                id="email"
                                label={language.emailLabel}
                                placeholder={language.emailLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                style={{}}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.email}
                                errors={errors.email}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="text"
                                name="userName"
                                label={language.usernameLabel}
                                placeholder={language.usernameLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="name"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.userName}
                                errors={errors.userName}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="password"
                                name="password"
                                label={language.passwordLabel}
                                placeholder={language.passwordLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="password"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.password}
                                errors={errors.password}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <TextInput
                                type="password"
                                name="confirmPassword"
                                label={language.passwordConfirmLabel}
                                placeholder={language.passwordConfirmLabel}
                                className="templateInput"
                                id="password"
                                onChange={onChange}
                                value={user.confirmPassword}
                                errors={errors.confirmPassword}
                            />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style={{marginTop: 30}}>
                        <Button onClick={onButtonPreviousClick}
                                name="btnPrevious"
                                value={language.btnPrevious}
                                icon="arrow-circle-left"
                                style={{marginRight: 10, float: 'right'}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style={{marginTop: 30}}>
                        <Button onClick={onButtonClick} name="stepTwoNext" value={language.btnNext}
                                icon="arrow-circle-right" style={{marginLeft: 10, float: 'left'}}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    );
};

export default RegistrationFormStepTwo;
```

Comment: What is TextInput?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is why the warning exists: When the value is specified as undefined, React has no way of knowing if you intended to render a component with an empty value or if you intended for the component to be uncontrolled. It is a source of bugs.

You could do a null/undefined check, before passing the value to the input.

[a source](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6222)

Comment: But why I'm not getting this warning without validation function? The validation function does nothing with the field values.

Comment: @Boky can you provide repo? you wrote obout "second step" ,but i didn't see that component

Comment: It's very similar to the first step. I updated my question. If I add something like `if(value == null || typeof value == "undefined"){
      fieldValue = "";
  }else{
      fieldValue = value;
  }` I do not get any warning but the it wont go to the second step. If I remove validation function it works perfect.

Comment: @Boky try to define `defaultValue="test"` prop in input. or `value={value || "test" }`, for testing purpose

Comment: you can't get step 2 because your validation returns false > because if(!user.firstName) return false > because you set  fieldValue = "". i guess))

Comment: with another words,you attemp to valide field on second step before as you open that step. But it field is empty, therefore you can't get second step. Sorry for my english

Comment: Yes. You are right. I changed my validation function and it works. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Kokovin Vladislav is right. To put this in code, you can do this in all your input `value`s:

```
<TextInput
    // your other code
    value={user.firstName || ''}
/>
```

That is, if you don't find the value of first name, then give it an empty value.