# In Redux Form, how can I set the initial value of the checked property of a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

In our Redux Form 5.3 (not 6.x) app, I want to render an `<input type="checkbox" />` like so:

```
// In some cases, fieldHelper.checked is initially undefined. Then, when the
// user clicks one of the checkboxes, fieldHelper.checked is
// explicitly set to true or false. This change from one of the component's
// props being undefined to having a value causes a React warning; see
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/38015169/473792 and
// https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
// So to prevent that warning, we do a quick null check on
// fieldHelper.checked and replace it with false explicitly if it is
// undefined before rendering the checkbox.
const fieldHelper = this.props.field['checkbox'];
const checked = fieldHelper.checked || false;

const modifiedFieldHelper = Object.assign({}, fieldHelper);
delete modifiedFieldHelper.checked;

return (
  <input
    checked={checked}
    {...modifiedFieldHelper}
  />
);
```

}

As noted in the comment, in my testing environment, `this.props.field['checkbox'].checked` is `undefined` immediately after mounting the `<input>`. As a result, when my tests modify the value of `this.props.field['checkbox'].checked`, I get the following warning:

> Warning: ApplicantForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

... Unless I explicitly set the [`checked` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#checked) on the `<input>` to `false` instead of `undefined`, as demonstrated in the code snippet I posted above.

Instead of using this null check, I would like to set the initial value of `this.props.fields['checkbox'].checked` before my tests run. [I know I can set the initial value of fields in Redux Form.](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/initializing-from-state) Is there a way to set the initial value of an auxiliary property like the `checked` property that Redux Form also controls?

Comment: Have you tried using a boolean?

Comment: It looks like Redux-Form currently has some bugs with how it works with checkboxes, so I may have run up against that: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/334

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a simple conditional in your checked attribute so that when the value is undefined you just return false:

```
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  checked={typeof this.props.fields['checkbox'].checked == 'undefined'?false:this.props.fields['checkbox'].checked} 
  onClick={() => {... your onClick code ...}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes are no different from text inputs. You can still just destructure the field object into your `<input>`. See how the `employed` value is used in the `v5.3.3` [Simple Form Example](https://redux-form.com/5.3.3/#/examples/simple).

```
<input type="checkbox" {...myField}/>
```

Redux Form will detect that it's a checkbox (really it detects for `boolean` values) and use the `checked` prop.

Comment: I understand how to destructure the field object into an `<input>`. What I want to do is set the initial value that the field object contains.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't see your last sentence. No, if your input is controlled by Redux-Form, you will need to initialize its value via the `initialValues` system.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used Redux-Form but to display the default checked value for a checkbox in default React you'll need to use the `defaultChecked` attribute. It accepts a boolean.

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={/*bool*/} />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help me. The reason I want to set the initial value of the `checked` prop is because I want the checkbox to be a controlled component, but in some situations, Redux Form initially sets the `checked` property to undefined, giving me a warning. I have more details about what I want to do in [an earlier, longer draft of my question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41452053/1).